# how to get element from this array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get data from an array.I have two sub-arrays in that array. One is at position `[0]` and another is at `['header_data']`. Initially I am able to extract `[0]` subscript elements but don't know how to get `['header_data']` elements. Code is given below :

```
foreach ($result as $index) {
        $resultArr[] = explode('      ', $index[0][0]);
    }

    //$valuesArr = array();
    foreach ($resultArr as $value) {

        $arrayVal = array("lead_source" => "ABC",
            "name" => trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array('Name  :  ', '(Dealer)'), '', $value[0]))),
            "emailId" => trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array('Email  :  ', 'Verified'), '', $value[1]))),
            "contactNo" => trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array('Phone number   :  ', '     Verified'), '', $value[2]))),
            "project_name" => " ",
            "customer_query" => "",
            "description" => "",
            "locality" => "",
            "budget" => "",
            "date" => $index['header_data']['date'],
            "subject" => $index['header_data']['subject']  
        );
```

Output is here :

```
    Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Kishor 
                [1] =>bisal@gjjil.com      
                [2]=> 845678956
            )

        [header_data] => Array
            (
                [date] => Sun, 5 Oct 2014 15:10:17 +0580
                [subject] => Advertisement Response for Dealer profile
            )

    )
```

Comment: Umm, `$arr['header_data']['date']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access associative array like this:

```
$arr['header_data']['date'] 
$arr['header_data']['subject']
```

Answer (score 0):

To access data from an associative array, where you have named keys:

```
 $array = array('peach' => 'melba', 'banana' => 'split');

 echo $array['peach'] . PHP_EOL;
 echo $array['banana'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
melba
split
```

To access data in a nested associative array:

```
$nest = array('peach' => 'melba', 'chocolate' => array( 'chip' => 'cookies', 'milk' => 'shake' ) );

echo $nest['chocolate']['chip'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $nest['chocolate']['milk'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
cookies
shake
```

Iterate through the array:

```
foreach ($nest['chocolate'] as $k => $v) {
    echo "key: $k, value: $v" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
key: chip, value: cookies
key: milk, value: shake
```